# NodeJS response has been sent before MySQL query execution

Tags: mysql, node.js

Here is my NodeJS code, I want to return csvFile array after the query executed, but I first return an empty array and then execute the query. I call getDetection function in getSummary function. Both functions are executing a query. Can anybody please help me?

```
function getSummary(req, res) {
  var result = [];
  var csvFile = new Array();
  //console.log(csvFile);
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if (err) {
          res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
          return;
        } 
    //var result = [];
    var option = req.body;
    //console.log(option.type);
    connection.query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM dgh WHERE name LIKE ? ", ['%' + option.type.toUpperCase() + '%'], 
      function(err, rows, fields) {

        connection.release();
         if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
           var row = rows[i].name;
           result.push(row);
           getDetection(result[i], function(result) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            } else {
            var count = result.count;
            var maxD = result.maxD;
            var array = new Array(count, maxD);
            csvFile.push(array); 
            //console.log(csvFile);
            }
           });
          }
        } 
    });  
  })

  console.log(csvFile);
  res.csv(csvFile);
}
```

getDetection function:

```
function getDetection(filename, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if (err) {
          res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
          return;
        }   
    connection.query("SELECT hour, minute, second FROM dgh WHERE name = ?", [filename], 
      function(err, rows, fields){
        connection.release();
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          var count = 0;
          var maxD = 0;
          for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var time1 = rows[i].hour * 3600 + rows[i].minute * 60 + rows[i].second;
            var time2 = rows[i - 1].hour * 3600 + rows[i - 1].minute * 60 + rows[i].second;
            if (time2 - time1 > 60) {
              count = count + 1;
              maxD = Math.max(maxD, time2 - time1);
            }
          }
          callback({count:count, maxD:maxD});
        }

    })

  })
}
```

Comment: Your `res.csv` call needs to happen inside the callback passed to `connection.query`, after the `for` loop building your `csvFile`.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply! I did what you said and add console.log(csvFile) right before res.csv(csvFile), but it still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is asynchronous. If **getDetection** is an asychronous function for loop will not execute as you expect.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
       var row = rows[i].name;
       result.push(row);
       getDetection(result[i], function(result) {
            if (err) {
               throw err;
            } else {
                var count = result.count;
                var maxD = result.maxD;
                var array = new Array(count, maxD);
                csvFile.push(array); 
                //console.log(csvFile);
            }
       })
    }
}
```

As of right now, for loop will just pass through **getDetection** function and finish iteration. This causes the variable **csvFile** to be empty.

I suggest you install the ***async*** package using **npm**.

```
npm install --save async
```

After installing

```
async.each(rows, function(name, callback) {
    result.push(name)
    getDetection(name, function(item){
        if (err) throw err

        var count = item.count
        var maxD = item.maxD
        var array = new Array(count, maxD)
        csvFile.push(array)
        callback()
    })
}, function(err){
    if (err) {
        //Handle error here that occurred during iteration
    } else { //finished all iteration
        console.log(csvFile)
        res.csv(csvFile)
        return 
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you veryyy much for help! I changed my code like you wrote, in function(err), both throw err and console.log(csvFile) don't print. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I add callback(null) and then console.log(csvFile) can be printed now. But it's still empty. You're right, getDetection is an asychronous function, do you think I should do something in getDetection Function?

Comment: Try printing out all the variables that you are pushing on to **csvFile**. See where there are variables that doesn't have any values. The flow of the code seems fine now